# NGINX Wont GZIP with user agent header passed

Tags: caching, nginx, gzip, user-agent

I'm using nginx 1.8.0 with php-fpm and I've been trying to get Nginx to gzip content. Everything seems to be configured correctly however I was not able to get gzip to work at all. I've trouble shot this all the way down to being related to the User-Agent in the request header. When the user agent comes in with a valid User-Agent string; gzip does not work. Using a "modify headers" extension for Firefox, if I disable the User-Agent in the header gzip works. Gzip is also working if I access the site via https. This is the only way I have gotten gzip to work with nginx as of now. What is the issue here? Refer here for my config files

[HTTPS GZIP NGINX WTF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949561/https-gzip-nginx-wtf)

Answer (score 0):

My issue had to do with

```
- 1 network load balancer
- 2 local anitvirus
```

The loadbalancer was unzipping the packets to inspect (we use A10's) and the antivirus was doing the same. After working with our network engineer to fix the load balancing issue which was simple switch I had to disable my local antivirus when developing to test this.